# Capturing the current DateTime of user registration using asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to capture the date and time of when a user is registered using my asp.net identity registerViewModel. I then want it to be added to the AspNetUsers table.

MODEL:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} 
        characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }


    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.UserName
        };

            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            model.GetDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Users.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I keep getting the error:

> 'Cannot convert from RegisterViewModel to ApplicationUser.'
>   'RegisterViewModel is not assignable to parameter type
>   ApplicationUser'.

This error is on the (model) bit of the following code:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
model.GetDate = DateTime.Now;
db.Users.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.Users.Add(model);
```

The `Users` table is a `Set<ApplicationUser>`. It only allows you to add `ApplicationUser` objects to it.

```
Register(RegisterViewModel model)
```

`model` is a parameter of type `RegisterViewModel`. This is not a parameter of type `ApplicationUser`, and can therefore not be added to the `Users` table.

I assume that what you want it this:

```
db.Users.Add(user);
```

Since `user` is of type `ApplicationUser`.

---

As a general tip, when you see the following error message:

> Cannot convert from **RegisterViewModel** to **ApplicationUser**.

You should read this as:

> You are trying to use a **RegisterViewModel** object when you should be using a **ApplicationUser** object. This does not compute. Use an object of the correct type.

Comment: Thanks very much Flater - particularly for the clear explanation. I am now getting this error though - 'The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: @DBoi: That is a completely different issue, occurring at a completely different layer (spoiler alert: it's related to your version of SQL database. Google can fill in the details). This warrants a new question, the current question is already answered.